# How to implement a tree structure in Python using namedtuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a key-word, e.g. friendly. It gives birth to a child-word, e.g. warm, while descending from a parent-word, e.g. friend.

```
from collections import namedtuple

keyword = 'friendly'
childword = 'warm'
parentword = 'friend'

connect=namedtuple(keyword,'children parents')
output = connect([childword],[parentword])
```

As a result, I can use output.children to see what are the children of my nodeword. However, what I really want to do is to type

```
friendly.children # instead of output.children
```

to see the children of the key-word friendly. How can I do this? I am completely new to Python; I am not even sure if this is doable.

Comment: Maybe a `namedtuple` is not the right data structure for what you're trying to do, but it's a little unclear.  Usually with questions like this it's best not to ask "How do I do _______ using specific tool _______?" and more "This is what I tried and here's why it didn't work; what could I do differently?"  Because maybe you didn't choose the right tool in the first place.  As it is the title of your question doesn't really mean anything useful.

Comment: If you're trying to build a tree structure, for example, which it sounds like you are, there are plenty of materials out there already and representing trees in Python.

Comment: How do I represent trees in Python?

Comment: I think classes may be closer to what you want

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define a tree structure, you could use a namedtuple for that:

```
from collections import namedtuple

TreeNode = namedtuple('TreeNode', ['word', 'children'])

friend = TreeNode(word='friend', children=[])
friendly = TreeNode(word='friendly', children=[])
warm = TreeNode(word='warm', children=[])

friend.children.append(friendly)
friendly.children.append(warm)

print(friendly.children)
```

which comes up with:

```
[TreeNode(word='warm', children=[])]
```

That's a very C-like way of doing things though; you're probably better off having a single Graph or Tree data structure that stores the edge relationships, eg:

```
children = dict()
children['friend'] = ['friendly']
children['friendly'] = ['warm']

def parents(word):
    ps = []
    for k in children:
        if word in children[k]:
            ps.append(k)
    return ps

print(children['friendly'])
print(parents('friendly'))
```

which comes up with

```
['warm']
['friendly']
```

There's an article on [Implementing Graphs in Python](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) available that you might find useful.